# I look for a common phrase containing umbrella or roof, etc. with connotation of unification

Tags: phrase-request

Consider a scenario (that I constructed to convey my intends):

1. We want to unify some people from different parts of a country, e.g. farmers.
2. These people have similar interests.

Now, consider my concocted sentences:

> We should bring people with same interests under a roof so that ... .
>
> We should bring people with same interests under an umbrella so that ... .

The above sentences have been translated word by word from my native language. I want to know whether English speakers have same phrases including "**umbrella**" or "**roof**"? If so, I will be happy to know about it.

---

More:

I know I can use the verbs like "**unify**", but I want to use idiomatic phrases. So, other suggestions will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the United States English, the colloquial term I have seen most used (from your examples) is the roof example, however I would word it slightly differently:

> We should bring people with similar interests under the same roof so that...

The key here is that the phrase we use is "under *the same* roof" not "under *a* roof"

This is still idiomatic, but I think it professionally gets your point across clearly.

Comment: Or *under **one** roof*.

Comment: Or *under the same umbrella*.